# How do I make a strongly typed AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a blazor Net 5.0 spa project

I would like to use a enum like this one for a strongly typed AuthorizeAttribute and AuthorizeView for Blazor components with added functionality like checking several roles exist instead either of many exists

Enum

```cs
    public enum RolesEnum
    {
       Access = 1,
       Administrator = 2
    }
```

How do I create an extended version of AuthorizeAttribute and AuthorizeView?

**Edit**

for a simple start I have tried making a class like this one without getting authorized.
I also tried adding it into services.

```
public class StrongRoleAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public StrongRoleAuthorizeAttribute(params RolesEnum[] rolesEnums) : base()
    {
        StrongRoles = rolesEnums;
    }

    private RolesEnum[] StrongRoles
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Roles.Split(",").Select(r => ClaimRoles.GetRolesTypeEnum(r)).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            this.Roles = string.Join(",", value.Select(r => r.RolesEnumToStringClaim()));
        }
    }
}
```

Edit2

I used the wrong method to convert to the claim value

Comment: What does "without luck" mean? **Be specific.**

Comment: thanks to your comment I checked again and I have used a wrong extension on my enum

Comment: There is no need to create a custom attribute. Look at policies this can perform what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply inherit the attribute :

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
   private readonly RolesEnum _authorizedRole;
  
   public MyAuthorizeAttribute(RolesEnum authorizedRole) 
   {
      _autorizedRole = authorizedRole;
   }

   // Override any method you want to use your enum
}
```

And the usage would be :

```
[MyAuthorize(RolesEnum.Administrator)]
```

Comment: I have tried that path without luck. I have updated question